# How can I pass values loaded by ajax to components?

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I'm passing a value as a parameter to a component.

`<badge-button params="badge: oarBadge"></badge-button>`

Here is the viewModel containing oarBadge:

```
function AppViewModel() {

            var self = this;

            self.oarBadge = ko.observable();

            $.getJSON('/guy.json', function(data) {
                var badge = new Badge('wood oar', data.badges.oar, false);
                self.oarBadge(badge);
                // self.oarBadge().has() returns true so the badge is being properly created with data
                // returned by the ajax call
            });

        } // AppViewModel()
```

Here is the Badge constructor:

```
function Badge(name, has, active) {
            var self = this;
            self.name = ko.observable(name);
            self.has = ko.observable(has);
            self.active = ko.observable(active);
            self.disabled = ko.computed(function() {
                return self.has();
            });
            self.toggleActive = function() {
                self.active(!self.active())
            };
            self.toggleHas = function() {
                self.has(!self.has());
            };
        }
```

Here is the component's viewModel:

```
ko.components.register('badge-button', {

            viewModel: function(params) {

                var self = this;
                self.badge = params.badge();

                self.open = function() {
                    self.badge.toggleHas();
                    self.badge.toggleActive();
                }

            },

            template: 
                '<img class="ui image" src="http://fakeimg.pl/300/" data-bind="click: open, css: { disabled: badge.disabled }" >'

        });
```

When the page loads, I get an error telling me that badge is undefined.

Full example: https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/5a8763ff71f90e3fe8b4b153ed9a5283

Comment: getJSON is an async function, so the value in the "oarBadge" observable is undefined until you get response. And you get the error on the first render while "oarBadge" observable is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a default object before the ajax call is completed, also you should assign the observable itself not the evaluation for the observable, so instead of doing this:

```
self.badge = params.badge();
```

You should do it like this:

```
self.badge = params.badge;
```

Otherwise your variable won't be updated once the ajax request is completed.

Here is a small example: https://jsfiddle.net/b0bdru1u/1/

Note: As far as I know the disable binding won't work in images